# To update a yaml file using yq command through jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, yaml, yq

My sample yaml file looks like:

```
cluster:
  a: val1
  b: val2
  c: val3
  list:
    k1:
    - n11
    - n2
    k2:
    - n1
```

So, the jenkins pipeline takes 2 inputs, i.e., the name of the input1 and input2. Post creation, I need to update the yaml file. I need to add the input1 based on input2, if input2=k1, I need to input1 in k1 section. I'm trying to execute the following command in my jenkins pipeline:
`sh "a=$Input1 b=$Input2 yq -i '.cluster.list[strenv(b)] += strenv(a)' sample.yaml"`

But it is throwing error:

```
jq: error: strenv/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.cluster.vms[strenv(a)] += strenv(b)
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) while actually using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq). Both are named `yq` and also roughly accomplish the same tasks. Yet, only the former has a function called `strenv` while the latter uses [stedolan/jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) under the hood, as you can see with your error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1: if your variable is declared in the pipeline:
`yq -iY .cluster.list[$key] += $val`
where, -iY will edit the yaml file, $key holds the value of input1 and $val holds the value of input2

Case 2: if $key and $val are not declared, following commands work:
`yq -iY --arg key k1(or k2) --arg val value .cluster.list[$key] += $val`